# GROUP BY one column; pick arbitrary value for another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select one row per user. I don't care which image I get. This query works in MySQL, but not in SQL Server:

```
SELECT user.id, (images.path + images.name) as 'image_path'
FROM users
JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: What is the aggregation logic for selecting an image?

Comment: IOW, if a user has more than one image, which one do you want?

Comment: just one image doesnt matter

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't tell SQL Server "any image will do."

Comment: *"This query works in MySQL"* It works but not always as you expect. There is a reason that it is not allowed in all other DBMS.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ why? What could happen unexpectedly? Why can't the server just output it in the order it was stored in or some other convenient way?

Comment: @lucidbrot what could happen is that a user can have more than one related images. And - it does happen in MySQL that allows this - a path is chosen from one (image) row and a name from another (image) row. And the result you get doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want a specific order for the image chosen for a user, you can use PaulWhite's CROSS APPLY solution (just add your custom ORDER BY inside the TOP (1) subquery).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Ah, so what you're saying is that GROUP BY might mix the rows content of the same group. Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solutions posted so far using a `MIN/MAX` aggregate or `ROW_NUMBER` may not be the most efficient (depending on data distribution) since they will generally have to inspect all matching rows before choosing one per group.

Using the [AdventureWorks sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) to illustrate, the following queries all choose a single `TransactionType` and `ReferenceOrderID` from the Transaction History table for each `ProductID`:

#### Using a `MIN`/`MAX` aggregate

```
SELECT
    p.ProductID,
    MIN(th.TransactionType + STR(th.ReferenceOrderID, 11))
FROM Production.Product AS p
INNER JOIN Production.TransactionHistory AS th ON
    th.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY
    p.ProductID;
```

[image: Aggregate query plan]

#### Using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        th.ProductID, 
        th.TransactionType, 
        th.ReferenceOrderID,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY th.ProductID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Production.TransactionHistory AS th
)
SELECT
    p.ProductID,
    x.TransactionType,
    x.ReferenceOrderID
FROM Production.Product AS p
INNER JOIN x ON x.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE
    x.rn = 1
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

[image: Row number plan]

#### Using the internal-only `ANY` aggregate

```
SELECT
    q.ProductID, 
    q.TransactionType, 
    q.ReferenceOrderID 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        p.ProductID, 
        th.TransactionType, 
        th.ReferenceOrderID,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY p.ProductID 
            ORDER BY p.ProductID)
    FROM Production.Product AS p
    JOIN Production.TransactionHistory AS th ON p.ProductID = th.ProductID
) AS q
WHERE
    q.rn = 1;
```

For details on the `ANY` aggregate, see [this blog post](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2011/07/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.html).

[image: ANY aggregate]

#### Using a correlated sub-query with a non-deterministic `TOP`

```
SELECT p.ProductID,
    (
    -- No ORDER BY, so could be any row
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        th.TransactionType + STR( th.ReferenceOrderID, 11)
    FROM Production.TransactionHistory AS th WITH (FORCESEEK) 
    WHERE
        th.ProductID = p.ProductID
    )
FROM Production.Product AS p;
```

[image: TOP 1]

#### Using `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP (1)`

The previous query requires concatenation and returns a `NULL` for products with no transaction history. Using `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP` resolves both issues:

```
SELECT
    p.Name, 
    ca.TransactionType,
    ca.ReferenceOrderID
FROM Production.Product AS p
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        th.TransactionType,
        th.ReferenceOrderID
    FROM Production.TransactionHistory AS th WITH (FORCESEEK) 
    WHERE 
        th.ProductID = p.ProductID
) AS ca;
```

[image: CROSS APPLY plan]

With optimal indexing, and if each user typically has many images, the `APPLY` may be the most efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If a user has multiple images, and you only want one image, which one do you want? While MySQL has loosy-goosy syntax that doesn't force you to make a choice, just giving you any old arbitrary value, SQL Server makes you choose. One way is `MIN`:

```
SELECT u.id, MIN(i.path + i.name) AS image_path
FROM dbo.users AS u
INNER JOIN dbo.images AS i
ON u.id = i.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

You could also substitute `MAX` for `MIN`. And depending on the version of SQL Server, and whether in actuality you need more columns, there may be other ways to do this slightly more efficiently (avoiding some of the sort/group work). For example if you wanted the path and name separately, this won't work out so well:

```
SELECT u.id, MIN(i.path), MIN(i.name)
FROM dbo.users AS u
INNER JOIN dbo.images AS i
ON u.id = i.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

...since you could theoretically get path and name from two different rows, and this result would no longer make sense. So instead you could do this:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT user_id, path, name, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM dbo.images
)
SELECT u.id, x.path, x.name
FROM dbo.users AS u
INNER JOIN x
ON u.id = x.user_id
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Whether it makes sense to use this variation in your existing case depends heavily on how these two tables are indexed, but you could try this approach and compare the plans / performance:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT user_id, path + name AS image_path, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM dbo.images
)
SELECT u.id, x.image_path
FROM dbo.users AS u
INNER JOIN x
ON u.id = x.user_id
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

(And try replacing `SELECT NULL` with the leading column in a narrow index in `dbo.images`.)

P.S. Don't use `AS 'alias'` syntax. That form is deprecated and makes the alias look like a string literal. Also [use the schema prefix always](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and use aliases so you don't have to repeat complete table names all over the query...

Answer (score 3):

You need an aggregate function. The *right* aggregate function is application-dependent. That means you're the only one who can tell.  One primitive hack at it:

```
SELECT user.id, max((images.path + images.name)) as 'image_path'
FROM users
JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

MySQL's handling of the GROUP BY clause is widely regarded as [BAD](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/BAD.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use Max or Min as required:

```
SELECT user.id, max(images.path + images.name) as image_path
FROM users
      JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This selects the first (alphabetical) entry if multiple images are available for one user

```
SELECT user.id, min(images.path + images.name) as image_path
FROM users
JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `GROUP BY` you can only use the columns you aggregate with and aggregate functions for the others.

Here is one way to achieve this:

```
SELECT user.id, (MAX(images.path) + MAX(images.name)) as 'image_path'
FROM users
JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Though you are more likely to want:

```
SELECT user.id, MAX(images.path + images.name)) as 'image_path'
FROM users
JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't generally count on `MAX(images.path) + MAX(images.name)` being a member of `images.path + images.name`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' - I don't follow.

Comment: @Oded - let say you have `\Folder1\Image2` and `\Folder2\Image1`. Your script returns `\Folder2\Image2` which simply does not exist.

Comment: @Oded I'm afraid they're correct. Now, maybe the OP doesn't care that the aggregation returns an invalid image path (after all, since they don't care which one, maybe it doesn't matter whether it's valid either), but strictly speaking I would not expect a result that combines values from multiple rows (I addressed this in my answer).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - It is a fair point, not saying it isn't. But that relies on assumptions regarding the application semantics and image directories layouts. It is easy enough to imagine where this would be a valid assumption.

Comment: @Oded but in general for this solution pattern I would suspect it's an assumption that rings true in very few cases. If one of the columns is always the same (say everything is in the same folder), then there's no real reason to include that column in the aggregation; you could just use a constant (and perhaps not even store it in the first place). In almost all cases I will suspect that users will expect all of the arbitrary columns to come from the same row, though I will concede that there may be edge cases where that doesn't matter either.

Comment: PS I didn't feel strongly enough about this to down-vote (in fact I up-voted after your addition). I do find it troubling that users are encouraged to accept the first answer as quickly as possible, since the first answer is not always the most informative or helpful.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Can't say I care too much about a single downvote like that. And I don't know if users are _encouraged_ as much as just trying to get closure. I don't like users accepting my answers too quickly either, in particular if there are no "competing" answers yet.

Comment: @Oded I know, just wanted to state so explicitly.